# Change RootViewController inside UISplitView

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitview

I'm developing a little example for iPad from a UISplitView XCode Template. It's formed by a root controller which is shown in the left of the window and a detail view which is shown in the right.

What I want to achieve is very simple (at least I think so) but I can't find in the documentation the way to do it.

I'd like to substitute the root controller (which appears fixed in the left) with a new controller (for example as response to a event launched when you push a button). I've tried this:

```
ColorPicker *controlador = [[ColorPicker alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.rootViewController presentModalViewController:controlador animated:YES];
[controlador release];
```

What happens with that is that the new pushed controller fills the entire window, whereas what I want is that appears fixed at the left with the two columns format that were at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pushViewController:animated` instead may fix this.  About ModalViewController, check document  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: Thanks Azu and Deepak. In this case that was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `modalPresentationStyle` to an appropriate value,

```
controlador.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

`UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` instructs the view controller to appear modally within the frame of the `rootViewController`.